# Schedule or run threads at the same time

Tags: python-3.x, async-await, concurrency, python-asyncio, python-multithreading

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.id = str(uuid.uuid4())


    async def do_action(self):
        ........
        ........


async def main():
    data = //something
    //some actions here
    for _ in range(1000):
        await Foo(data).do_action()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

In this case I need to do the action a 1000 times together using python async. So, can I schedule the await task and run the whole thing at the same time and use the for loop for just creating 1000 objects of the class Foo?

Please help. Explain a method which is more powerful and at the same time thin (avoid using other packages if possible)

Comment: You probably want something like `asyncio.gather`.

Comment: More information is needed. Do you need all individual results gathered before continuing or can you proceed with one at a time?